# Basic Proxy Authentication on chrome manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I use this method to handle the Proxy-Authorization on chrome manifest v2 but it doesn't work on manifest v3. What should I do in chrome/chromium manifest v3?

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details, callbackFn) {
        callbackFn({
            authCredentials: { username: username, password: password }
        });
    },{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},['asyncBlocking']);
```

Comment: ManifestV3 is still semi-broken so there's no solution, see https://crbug.com/1135492.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option for you, you could use devtools protocol to do this for now.
ref: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-continueWithAuth

Fetch can also handle auth in 3rd party iframes, which webRequests cannot.
But please keep in mind that you cannot use it in the combination with the declarativeNetRequests.

I also share the opinion that MV3 is still "semi-broken" and it is not able to handle many use-cases that we were able in MV2.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
It's Not What I'm looking for.
I don't want to send the HTTP request over proxy.
I want to set the HTTP(S) Proxy on chrome with basic authentication. so the Proxy-Authorization header should be set on each outgoing request on every website.